# Cleanly handling events

Tags: java, events

I have code similar to this in all my observer classes that handle events fired by an event bus class.
As you can see there are a lot of instanceof checks to choose the path of action needed to appropriately handle events, and I was wondering if this could be done more cleanly, eliminating the instanceof tests?

```
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (event instanceof DownloadStartedEvent) {
        DownloadStartedEvent dsEvent = (DownloadStartedEvent)event;
        dsEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new BusyDownloadingState());
    } else if (event instanceof DownloadCompletedEvent) {
        DownloadCompletedEvent dcEvent = (DownloadCompletedEvent)event;
        dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FinishedDownloadingState());
        DownloadCandidate downloadCandidate = dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem(). getDownloadCandidate();
        if (downloadCandidate.isComplete()) {
            // start extracting
        }
    } else if (event instanceof DownloadFailedEvent) {
        DownloadFailedEvent dfEvent = (DownloadFailedEvent)event;
        dfEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FailedDownloadingState());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a clean, object oriented way to do it. Other ways would use a parameter of the event with a switch waterfall.. why do you think this is not clear?

Comment: @Jack It's a maintenance nightmare if you expect to add more events later on: there will always be the one event you forget to check for.

Comment: if you have many events it would be maintenance nightmare anyway until you don't give to events common behaviour in ancestor classes instead that having all of them separated.. actually this when number_events > a_considerable_amount you will swear in any case :/

Comment: BTW, a list of instanceof checks is *never* a clean, object-oriented way to do things.

Comment: Why not? It's not spaghetti code and you don't end up having handling of events (that is a common factor) all over your project. So you can say it's not elegant but it's still clean..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could eliminate the events by adding listeners for each event in turn. Consider for instance

```
public void handleStartedEvent(DownloadStartedEvent ev) { ... }
public void handleCompletedEvent(DownloadCompletedEvent ev) { ... }
public void handleFailedEvent(DownloadFailedEvent ev) { ... }
```

You may also consider combining Completed/Failed into a single event since it looks like you already have an isCompleted method. You could handle CompleteEvent and check for success. If successful you could start extracting otherwise you could set your failure state.

My other thought would be why are you setting a new object as a state indicator. Could that perhaps be better served using constants/enum values?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you control the `Event` class, and/or its subclasses. You could add an abstract `handle` method to your `Event` class, and move the specific code for each subclass into that method.

It would look like this:

```
abstract class Event {
  //...
  public abstract void handle();
}

class DownloadStartedEvent extends Event {
  //...
  @Override
  public void handle() {
    getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new BusyDownloadingState());
  }
}

// The same for the other classes
```

In your calling code, you simply write:

```
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
  event.handle();
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it will somehow break encapsulation, an event shouldn't try to handle itself :)

Comment: @Jack Depends on the situation, I think. If you really don't like it, you can add a parallel tree of handler classes and have the event delegate to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can come up with a cleaner solution using annotations. You'll need to define `@EventHandler` and `@HandlesEvent`, then use it like:

```
@EventHandler
public class MyEventHandler {

   @HandlesEvent(DownloadStartedEvent.class)
   public void handleDownloadStartedEvent(DownloadStartedEvent dse) {
      dsEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new BusyDownloadingState());
   }

   @HandlesEvent(DownloadCompletedEvent.class)
   public void handleDownloadCompletedEvent(DownloadComletedEvent dse) {
      dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FinishedDownloadingState());
      DownloadCandidate downloadCandidate = dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem(). getDownloadCandidate();
      if (downloadCandidate.isComplete()) {
            // start extracting
      }
   }


   // etc.

}
```

Of course you'll need additional code to register this class and it will need to use reflection to check which method handles which event. Your observables then interact with this registrar which in turn interacts with the above @EventHandler annotated class.

Answer (score 0):

if what you need to do is just to instantiate "states" like `BusyDownloadedState` or `FinishedDownloadedState` you could give your `Event` class an attribute that states which is the state that must be set according to the kind of event.

If you need to have both simple events and complex events you can have a mix of two things:

```
class Event
{
   State state;
   boolean isSimple;
}

public void handleEvent(Event event)
{
  if (event.isSimple)
    setState(event.state)
  else
  {
     if (event instanceof WhateverEvent)
        // special handling
  }
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this, is if there are lots of special cases, you end up with a more complex variant of the original code.

Comment: Yes, you should choose granularity of this thing accurately.. of course we don't know enough about how many events or kinds of events he needs to give a perfect solution for his case.. actually in a similar case I'll end up refactoring the whole thing as soon as I realize that specification needs something different..

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Ryan's answer, instead of having a separate method for each event, you can use generics. Then you could write:

```
public void registerListeners() {

eventSource.addListener(DownloadStartedEvent.class, new EventHandler<DownloadStartedEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(DownloadStartedEvent event) {
        dsEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new BusyDownloadingState());
    }
});

eventSource.addListener(DownloadCompletedEvent.class, new EventHandler<DownloadCompletedEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(DownloadCompletedEvent event) {
        dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FinishedDownloadingState());
        DownloadCandidate downloadCandidate = dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem(). getDownloadCandidate();
        if (downloadCandidate.isComplete()) {
            // start extracting
        }
    }
});

eventSource.addListener(DownloadFailedEvent.class, new EventHandler<DownloadFailedEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(DownloadFailedEvent event) {
        dfEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FailedDownloadingState());
    }
});
}
```

I leave the implementation of addListener() as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public void handleEvent(Event e) {
   // Not interested
}


public void handleEvent(DownloadStartedEvent dsEvent) {
    dsEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new BusyDownloadingState());
}


public void handleEvent(DownloadCompletedEvent dcEvent) {
    dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FinishedDownloadingState());
    DownloadCandidate downloadCandidate = dcEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().getDownloadCandidate();
    if (downloadCandidate.isComplete()) {
        // start extracting
    }
}

public void handleEvent(DownloadFailedEvent dfEvent) {
    dfEvent.getDownloadCandidateItem().setState(new FailedDownloadingState());
}
```